# Text file to dictionary then to print information in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Hey everyone just have an issue with a text file and putting it into a dictionary.

So my code first starts off by gathering data from a website and writes it to a text file. From there I reopen the file and make it into a dictionary to transfer the data from the text to the dictionary. In the while loop, I am getting the error of

```
 key,value = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Which I'm not sure why if I'm using the wrong method to write the text file data to the new place in the program of "countryName"

```
def main():
    import requests
    webFile = "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/rawdata_2004.txt"
    data = requests.get(webFile) #connects to the file and gest a response object
    with open("capital.txt",'wb') as f:
        f.write(data.content) #write the data out to a file – wb used since thecontent from the response object is returned as abinary object.
    f.close()
    infile = open('capital.txt', 'r')
    line = infile.readline()
    countryName = {}
    while line != "":
        key,value = line.split() 
        countryName[key] = value
        line = infile.readline()
    infile.close()
    userInput = input("Enter a country name: ")
    for i in countryName:
        while(userInput != 'stop'):
            print("The per capita income in",countryName[key], "is",countryName[value])
            userInput = input("Enter a country name: ")
main()
```

```
    while line != "":
        key,value = line.split() 
        countryName[key] = value
        line = infile.readline()
    infile.close()
```

This is where my issue pops up.

I am trying to have the text file information be put into a dictionary.
Once done I want to iterate through the dictionary, and have the user enter a country name. Then in response, the program finds the country name and returns the name of the country and the capital income as well.

So if "United States" is inputed the output would be "The per capita income in the United States is $54000" That as an example to show what im doing.

The key being the country name and the value being the income.

`countryName = {}
    with open('capital.txt','r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            num,key,value = line.split()
            countryName[key] = value
            num,key,value = infile.readline().split()
        #print(line)
    print(countryName)`

Comment: I think we'd need to see some example fines from the file to help here.

Comment: `line.split()` on your example yields three values. For example on the first line `['1', 'Liechtenstein', '$139,100']`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the lines return three values each: The line number, the country, and the per-capita income:

```py
fh.readline().split()
['2', 'Qatar', '$124,500']
```

To fix that, you can capture that third value in a throwaway variable:

```py
n, key, val = fh.readline().split()
```

However, there's a different problem, what if your country name has spaces in it?

```py
['190', 'Micronesia,', 'Federated', 'States', 'of', '$3,400']
```

You can use the `*arg` syntax to capture any number of arguments in a variable:

```py
myline = ['190', 'Micronesia,', 'Federated', 'States', 'of', '$3,400']

num, *key, value = myline

# key is now ['Micronesia,', 'Federated', 'States', 'of']
```

You can then use `join` to create a single string

```py
key = ' '.join(key)
# 'Micronesia, Federated States of'
```

Furthermore, it's important to keep your conventions consistent in your program. You use the `with` context handler to open and close an earlier file, that's a good practice, so keep it with the other file as well. Also, you can iterate over the file-handle directly like so:

```py
with open('capital.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile: # no need to check the line contents or call readline
        num, *key, value = line.split()
        key = ' '.join(key)

# No need to close your file at the end either
```

Last, your print statement will raise a `KeyError`:

```py
print("The per capita income in",countryName[key], "is",countryName[value])
```

You've already stored `value` at `countryName[key]`, so the lookup is only against `key`, rather than `value`:

```py
# key is already a string representing the country name
# countrName[key] is the value associated with that key
print("The per capita income in", key , "is", countryName[key])
```

Comment: For some odd reason i am still getting too many values to unpack using num, key, value @C.Nivs

Comment: @l.m I had an error in my answer. Edited. If you were to print the output of `infile.readline().split()`, what would that give you? I copied your link directly

Comment: @l.m What do the first two lines in that file look like when you print them?

Comment: I was trying to add it in the comment but I edited the original post at the bottom is what I did. I'm not sure if I put the code in the wrong place. @C.Nivs

Comment: @l.m  I found the issue, I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: So the error for the second part where i put the readline.split at the end is erroring for the too many values @C.Nivs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191867/discussion-between-c-nivs-and-l-m).